# Как построить composer.json?

Tags: php, composer

Репозитория https://github.com/Danilovonline/sLog

Не могу настроить, чтобы потом можно было через composer установить.

Comment: Читали https://getcomposer.org/doc/ ?

Comment: Читал. Пока не получается

Comment: @Danilovonline ну покажите ваш composer.json, не стесняйтесь

Comment: Вот https://github.com/Danilovonline/sLog/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: 1. name в формате vendor/package
2. версию убрать, ее не нужно руками проставлять
3. psr-0 нужен только для обратной совместимости, используйте psr-4
4. желательно давать ссылки на issues и сурсы на гитхабе

все остальное вроде в порядке и ничего не отсутствует

описание схемы здесь: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md

Comment: @Etki, спасибо. Подправлю

Answer (score 1):

Помогло обсуждение https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion

Добавил "minimum-stability"